# Create Conditional Page View on Laravel by User Type

Tags: php, laravel, view, routes, laravel-5

Does anyone know how to get this done? I'm trying to create a condition in Laravel's route. That if a type of user(example: Admin), the Dashboard page will be different from other types of user(example: Client).

See image here ->http://screenshots.screencast-o-matic.com/screenshot/u/n5AH/1448537774091-31837.png

Noticed: They should go in the same URL domain.com/dashboard. The page that will be rendered to the view must reflect to the type of user that's login.

Idea, anyone? thank you so much!!

Comment: Have a look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Comment: Why don't you pass the roles for both users and check it role wise

Comment: In laravel 5 and 5.1 we use middlewares not filters

Answer (score 2):

You may not want to do this in your routes. You should probably do this on your controller.

Say you have a PageController@dashboard method

```
public function dashboard() {
    if($user->admin) {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    return view ('user.dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with same route pointing to two actions, always the last action will be called, so the best way to do this is via `middleware`,

you need to go to `app/Http/Middleware` and create a `class isAdministrator` for example, it should look like this :

```
<?php

namespace TPS\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class IsAdministrator
{ 

    public function __construct(Guard $auth) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // I don't know how you verify that your user is an admin or not
        // but here we have a role wich can contain many roles
        if (! strpos($this->auth->user()->role, 'Administrateur')) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Forbidden.', 403);
            } else {
                // now here you will redirect to the normal user dashboard
                Redirect::route('user.dashboard');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

now you need to register your middleware and give it a name, go to `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add your middleware to the following array :

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'          => \TPS\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic'    => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest'         => \TPS\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
// I called it admin
    'admin'         => \TPS\Http\Middleware\IsAdministrator::class,
];
```

now you can attach this middleware to your administration dashboard route like so (you need to use named routes, it will be of use when you need to change some urls):

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'as' => 'admin.dashboard', 'uses' => 'PagesController@userType1'
]);
```